# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.isReleased(FacesContext.java:609)

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jsf-2, spring-webflow

I am integrating SWF 2.2.1,Primefaces 2.2.1,JSF 2,Spring Security 3,Spring 3.1.0M1.
I am able to hit my first page mentioned in Spring web-flow xml, but getting following error.

```
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/WEB-INF/flows/AccSrch/searchAccIns.xhtml]
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.isReleased(FacesContext.java:609)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.updateFacesContext(PartialViewContextImpl.java:468)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.isAjaxRequest(PartialViewContextImpl.java:108)
at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.isAjaxRequest(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:117)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.getRendersChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1020)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1755)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.renderView(FlowViewHandler.java:99)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.render(FlowLifecycle.java:80)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.render(JsfView.java:90)
```

And to my surprise I only have minimal code in my .xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
   <ui:define name="content">
      <f:view>
         <h:form id="expire" prependId="false">
            <h:outputText value="HEllo" />
         </h:form>
      </f:view>
   </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Please see this post also for the context
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173114/getting-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-faces-component-behavior-cli)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some facts:

- According to the appearance of Tomcat specific classes in the stacktrace in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173114/getting-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-faces-component-behavior-cli) you're using Tomcat.
- According to the appearance of the JSF 2.1 introduced [`FacesContext#isReleased()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isReleased%28%29) method in the stacktrace in your current question, you're using JSF 2.1.
- According to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173114/getting-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-faces-component-behavior-cli/6173338#6173338) in your other question, you're probably using Mojarra 2.1.0.
- Mojarra 2.1.0 [does not work](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/2.1.0/issues.html) in Tomcat/Jetty due to a [major mistake](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1937) of accidently introducing Glassfish specific code in the annotation scanning implementation for containers which does not ship with builtin annotation scanners.

So, to solve this problem there are several options:

- Downgrade to Mojarra 2.0.5.
- Upgrade to Mojarra 2.1.1.
- Replace Tomcat by Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6 or something else.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Tomcat? If so, revert back JSF version from 2.1.0 to the latest 2.0.x stable release, according to [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?106513-SWF-2.3-amp-JSF-2.1-UnsupportedOperationException-at-javax.faces.context.FacesContext) thread.

Comment: This is even more weird. I have downgraded my jsf-api and jsp-impl to 2.0.3. Now the page is coming, at the same time I am also getting same error in the console(error that I had posted in this question). Shall I change the tomcat with something else. Please suggest.

Comment: I solved it by changing the Primefaces version from 2.2.1 to 2.2.RC2.
Thanks for all the help!!!